# Given three customers arrive in the first hour, find probability third arrives in second half

Tags: uniform-distribution, poisson-process, gamma-distribution

Assume customers arrive according to a Poisson process with rate $\lambda = 3$.

Given three customers arrive in the first hour, find the probability that the third customer arrives in the second half of the hour.

So that is if $X_3$ is the third arrival time: $P(X_3 \in [0.5,1] \mid N(1) = 3)$

and we have $X_3 \sim$ Gamma$(3,3)$.

To solve this I have cases : $\bigg \{X_1,X_2 \in [0,.5]$ and $X_3 \in [.5,1]\bigg\}$ or

$\bigg \{X_1 \in [0,.5]$ and $X_2,X_3 \in [.5,1]\bigg\}$ or $\bigg \{X_1,X_2, X_3 \in [.5,1] \bigg \}$

However, isn't there a way to solve this using the Uniform distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that exactly three events were observed in the first hour, the distribution of their event times are independent and uniform over that hour.  So the probability the third event occurs in the second half hour is equal to the complement of the probability that all three events occur in the first half hour.  But the probability of all three events occurring in the first half hour is simply $(1/2)^3 = 1/8$; therefore, the desired answer is $1 - 1/8 = 7/8$.

Comment: So if I were to change the situation to one occurring in the first half-hour and two in the second half hour, we would get the same result by a symmetrical argument, correct?

Comment: That is not quite correct because to say that the first event occurs in the first half-hour does not in itself say anything about whether the second and third events occur in the second half hour.  Analogously, in the original question, the desired probability is that the third event occurs in the second half hour, saying nothing about the times for first two events.  Your statement imposes an additional condition that the other events occur in the other half hour.

Comment: @oliverjones To illustrate:  if $(x_{(1)}, x_{(2)}, x_{(3)})$ are the event times of the first, second, and third events, such that $0 \le x_{(1)} \le x_{(2)} \le x_{(3)} \le 1$, then the outcome $(0.6, 0.7, 0.8)$ satisfies the original question's condition, as does $(0.1, 0.2, 0.8)$.  The symmetric situation would be $(0.2, 0.3, 0.4)$ and $(0.2, 0.8, 0.9)$, but only this last outcome would satisfy your condition that the first event occurs in the first half hour and the second and third events occur in the second half hour.

Comment: I think what confused me is the statement 'So the probability the third event occurs in the second half hour is equal to the complement of the probability that all three events occur in the first half hour. '. Is the complement of $_1,_2,_3 \in [0,5]$ that at least one occurs in the second half hour which forces the third event to be in the second half based off of ordering? Maybe it would make more sense to me if I find these probabilities using order statistics.

Comment: @oliverjones Think of it this way.  You pick three numbers uniformly at random from $[0,1]$.  That's your set of event times, which are IID uniform.  Then you sort them in increasing order.  The sorted list is your *observed* event times, which is also uniform but they're no longer independent of each other because they must be in order.  In particular, the third event must always be the largest, so if the third event does **not** occur in the second half hour, all of the events occur in the first half hour.

Comment: Okay thank you! That clears it up, didn't initially occur to me to think of them not only as uniformly distributed but also in terms of order statistics.

Answer (score 3):

I think the key to solving this problem is to identify the following relationship: $$\{N(1)=3\}=\{X_3\leq 1,X_4>1\}$$ This way we can say $$P\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\leq X_3 \leq 1\bigg|N(1)=3\bigg)=\frac{P\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\leq X_3 \leq 1,X_4>1\bigg)}{P(N(1)=3)}$$ Using the total law of probability, $$P\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\leq X_3 \leq 1,X_4>1\bigg)=\int_{1/2}^1P\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\leq X_3 \leq 1,X_4>1\bigg|X_3=t\bigg)f_{X_3}(t)dt$$ Since inter$-$arrival times are independent and $\sim \exp(3)$ we have $$P\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\leq X_3 \leq 1,X_4>1\bigg|X_3=t\bigg)=\int_{1-t}^{\infty}3e^{-3t}dt=e^{3t-3}$$ Using the fact that $X_3 \sim \text{Erlang}(3,3)$ and $N(1)\sim \text{Poisson}(3)$ we get $$P\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\leq X_3 \leq 1,X_4>1\bigg)=\int_{1/2}^1e^{3t-3}f_{X_3}(t)dt=\frac{63}{16e^3}$$ $$P(N(1)=3)=\frac{27}{6e^3}$$ Dividing these two gives us our desired probability: $$P\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\leq X_3 \leq 1\bigg|N(1)=3\bigg)=\frac{7}{8}$$